# Node, JS and Eclipse

Tags: javascript, node.js, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, enide

I am attempting to create and launch Node projects through Eclipse but, until now, I have not succeded in doing it.

More precisely, when I try to install the Enide plugin through the Eclipse-MarketPlace I get the error:

> The following solutions are not available: Enide (Studio) 2015 - Node.js, JavaScript, Java and Web Tools 1.0.2 (id=org.sweetlemonade.eclipse.json.feature.feature.group, org.nodeclipse.pluginslist.feature.feature.group, de.bastiankrol.startexplorer.feature.feature.group, zipeditor.feature.group, code.satyagraha.gfm.viewer.feature.feature.group, org.nodeclipse.phantomjs.feature.feature.group, com.github.eclipsecolortheme.feature.feature.group, org.nodeclipse.enide.gradle.feature.feature.group, markdown.editor.feature.feature.group, org.nodeclipse.enide.nodejs.feature.feature.group, code.google.restclient.tool.feature.feature.group, gitaddon.feature.feature.group, jdt.spelling.feature.feature.group, org.dadacoalition.yedit.feature.group, org.nodeclipse.enide.editors.gradle.feature.feature.group, net.mihai-nita.ansicon.feature.group, pm.eclipse.editbox.feature.feature.group, site=https://nodeclipse.github.io/updates/)

What's wrong? What should I do?

My Eclipse version is the latest one:

```
Eclipse IDE for Enterprise Java and Web Developers (includes Incubating components)
Version: 2023-03 (4.27.0)
Build id: 20230309-1520
```

just downloaded and installed.

However, when I open the marketplace dialog I see some strange 'Unnamed solution':

[image]

Moreover, I cannot drag-and-drop the Enide plugin through the web-page: [enide-web-page](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/enide-studio-2015-nodejs-javascript-java-and-web-tools)

rendered by

```
FireFox 111.0.1 (64-bit)
```

Thus, I haven't been able, until now, to install the plugin. Could you, please, suggest me any further options?

Comment: Check the supported Eclipse Versions on its Marketplace page. It does not support current releases.

Comment: @nitind yes, thanks. However, after having installed the compatible 2021-03 (4.19.0)  version of Eclipse, I still have the problem: the 'Unnamed solution' has disappeared, however, I still cannot install the plugin.

Answer (score 2):

For anyone encountering the same problem.

Finally, I've succeded in installing the Enide 2015 plugin by downloading the plugin as an archive file: Eclipse allows to install plugins also as local archives.

The procedure is described in the option c) of the  [nodeclipse installation instructions](https://nodeclipse.github.io/updates/). The previous option b) suggests the features to select for installation from the whole archive.

*P.S.*
*Let me update my answer by specifying that I have finally leaved `Eclipse` in favour of another IDE better supporting `javascript`.*

Comment: can you specify which IDE has better support for javascript? is it vs code?

Comment: @Manohar Bhat Indeed, it is. I've been using it happily ever since.